# SQL IN condition cakephp

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, find, cakephp-1.3

let's say I have a column in my database table that contains a list of comma-separated values like:

```
MyTable.values = a,b,c,d,e,f,etc....
```

How do I construct the condition in the find('all') function of cakePHP to retrieve the entries whose MyTable.values contain let's say "c" for example

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the LIKE operator. Percent-sign is a wildcard.

```
<?php

$this->Model->find("all", array(
    "conditions" => array("Model.field LIKE" => "%c%")
));
?>
```

Gotta love that automagic.

**Edit:** Found it! The [complex find conditions page](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions) has official documentation on this, though it's kind of buried.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question, I don't want to know if a field in my database is within my list of comma-separated value, I want to know if my comma-separated value contains a word

Comment: @user765368, my apologies. fix't.

Comment: I know I could do this with LIKE, but apparently there are speed issues with using LIKE, so I wanted to do it with the sql IN condition. So is this not possible at all to do using IN?

Comment: @user765368, LIKE isn't as expensive as you might think. As long as you limits/sort your data so you're not returning thousands of rows, LIKE shouldn't be an issue. 

You could do it in code, as user1074115 is demonstrating below. But that's essentially what LIKE does, just with SQL.

If there's only a limited set of keywords, you could normalize your data?